# How to change steam tray icon size in gnome-session-flashback

Tags: gnome, icons, steam, gnome-classic, system-tray

I have a **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit** desktop with **gnome-session-flashback (metacity)** desktop environment.  *gnome-panel* tray icons have normal size of **24x24**.  I recently installed steam from Ubuntu repository via *apt-get*.

```
$ sudo apt-get install steam
```

After installation I launched *steam*, it downloaded updates and then I signed in.  After that I noticed *huge* (probably **48x48**) steam tray icon in *gnome-panel*.

[image: steam 48x48 tray icon in 24x24 panel]

I had a simmilar problem with *wallch* which I solved by resizing the app icons in `/usr/share/wallch/files/indicator_THEME_normal.png` but unfortunately for *steam* there is no `/usr/share/steam` folder.  However I searched `/usr/share/pixmaps` and there found two related icons.

```
$ cd /usr/share/pixmaps
$ ll steam*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Sep 13 19:39 steam.png -> ../icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Sep 13 19:39 steam_tray_mono.png -> ../icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam_tray_mono.png
```

Due to lack of colour in above output I'm also providing a screenshot below.
[image: original steam icons in pixmaps]
As I wanted 24x24 icons instead of 48x48, so I tried to replace those two icons with their 24x24 versions.

```
$ cd /usr/share/pixmaps
$ sudo rm steam*
$ sudo ln -s ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam.png
$ sudo ln -s ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam_tray_mono.png
$ ll steam*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Sep 14 11:37 steam.png -> ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Sep 14 11:37 steam_tray_mono.png -> ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam_tray_mono.png
```

Again due to lack of colour in above output I am providing a screenshot.
[image]

As can be seen from the two screenshots, *steam_tray_mono.png* is now red instead of cyan.  After that I again started steam with same 48x48 icons in tray.

So these are the things I tried to solve the problem but problem did not solve.  If anyone can help me to solve this issue I will be grateful.

Thank you.

### Update

After following Anwar's suggestion in his answer, I have fixed the broken symlink with `steam_tray_mono.png` in `/usr/share/pixmaps/`.  I just copied `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam_tray_mono.png` into my home folder, then scaled it to 24x24 using GIMP and finally moved the scaled image to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/`.  I deleted older symlinks and created new ones.

```
$ cd /usr/share/pixmaps
$ sudo rm steam*
$ sudo ln -s ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam.png
$ sudo ln -s ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam_tray_mono.png
$ ll steam*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Sep 14 12:14 steam.png -> ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam.png
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Sep 14 12:13 steam_tray_mono.png -> ../icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam_tray_mono.png
```

And here is the coloured screenshot.
[image: Fixed steam_tray_mono.png]

However, steam tray icon is **still** 48x48 pixels.  So I think *steam* is not using `steam_tray_mono.png`.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot's `ls -al`'s color output, The icon with 24x24 size worked with symlinking because there is a steam.png icon in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/`.

But the last `steam_tray_mono.png` didn't work. The symlink is broken (from the colored output). Because there is no `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam_tray_mono.png` icon.

I suggest you to resize the icon from `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam_tray_mono.png` with GIMP (or any other image editor) and put it in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/` folder. The symlink should work then.

Hope that will work.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue with broken symlink.  I have followed your instructions and successfully created a 24x24 `steam_tray_mono.png` in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/`.  I have also symlinked `steam.png` and `steam_tray_mono.png` from `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/` to`/usr/share/pixmaps/`.  But unfortunately even now when I start *steam*, I get the 48x48 icon as before.

Comment: @nlern Which icon there were you using?

Comment: I copied `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam_tray_mono.png` to my home directory, scaled it to 24x24 using GIMP and then moved it to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/`, as you suggested.  I deleted old *steam* symlinks from `/usr/share/pixmaps/` and created ones from `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/`.

Comment: I mean which icon theme you were using? Did you change it using any tweak tool?

Comment: I am using default icon theme `ubuntu-mono-dark`.  I have never changed it on my current Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @nlern That's good. Are you adding your own answer? I'm sorry because I couldn't help much. I didn't have Steam installed

Comment: I deleted `~/Steam` and also most subfolders in `~/.steam` (**except** `~/.steam/Steam`).  Then I ran `steam` and let it update itself.  After updating steam tray icon size was normal 24x24.  Now the funny thing is that I had also restored the symlinks in `/usr/share/pixmaps/` to original 48x48 ones.  Yet the tray icon is 24x24.  Also I deleted `steam_tray_mono.png` from `/usr/share/pixmaps` but still the tray icon size is 24x24!

Comment: I deleted my previous comment and added a new one.  I think I do not yet fully know what steps should be followed to exactly solve this issue.  So I think I will wait for more suggestions, answers for this issue and/or if I am able to get such one in future, I will mark it as a solution.  Also thank you for helping me in this issue.